# list variable contents into a separate file (unix)

Tags: variables, unix

I would like to have the contents of several variables in a file as one column. If I for example set my variables:

```
FILE1=1.txt
FILE2=2.txt
FILE3=3.txt
```

To grep all variables that start with FILE and are followed by a number I do:

`set | grep FILE[0-9] > LIST`

The contents are however just the variable names and not the contents i.e:

`head LIST`

```
FILE1
FILE2
FILE3
```

I would like to have:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

On a related question: I use `set` to print the variables. Is there a command that only prints the variables set in the current session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cut` for the this.

```
grep "FILE*" file | cut -d"=" -f2
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

where the options used are

```
-d, --delimiter=DELIM
       use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter
-f, --fields=LIST
       select only these fields;  also print any line that contains no delimiter character, unless the -s option is specified
```

Using `awk`, setting the IFS as `"="` and printing the 2nd column from the matched file.

```
awk -F"=" '/FILE*/{print $2}' file
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

To print all `name=value` pairs in your file, use the following script. Assuming your file has only these name-value pairs present

```
#!/bin/bash

setVariables=()
while IFS="=" read -r varName varValue;
do
setVariables+=("$varValue")
done <file
```

and print the values set in the `setVariables` as

```
for value in "${setVariables[@]}"
do
    echo "$value"
done
```

Comment: thank you! That works, however not with `compgen -A`. for this `set` should be used instead, which will print the variables and their contents. Thank you! Also, is there a better way to print the variables? I would like to just print all variables that were set in the current terminal session or by the script that I run.

Comment: @Vaxin: Refer my update to store all the set values in the file.

Answer (score 0):

To get the content of the variable FILE1 you could just eval the string "$FILE1".

```
list=$(compgen -A variable | grep '^FILE[0-9]$')
for line in $list
do
    eval echo '$'$line >> LIST
done
```

Don't forget the '^$' around your Regex. Otherwise even something like "HISTFILE1" would be matched.